# Using a constructor to fill a list overwrites previous information

Tags: c#, list, constructor

I'm still pretty new to C# so I do not know about all the possibilities that it has.

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Test ctest = new Test();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ctest.name = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(ctest.name);
            ctest.namelist.Add(ctest);
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = ctest.namelist;
        }
    }


    class Test
    {

        private string Name;

        public string name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }


        public List<Test> namelist = new List<Test>();

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string spaceinbetween = new string(' ', 3);
            return name + spaceinbetween + name;
        }
```

What I'm trying to do:
So I want to use my constructor to fill up my listbox with information (name in this case). However it overwrites previous values after adding more then 2 names.

I assume this goes wrong because the class object name gets overwritten and is used in both of the lines that where added.

Question: Is there anyway that adding a new name does not change the previous list values or is there any way to make a new instance of the constructor anytime I wanne create a new ctest?

Comment: The variable ctest is initialized only one time. Then you add this variable to the internal list every time you click the button but it is always the same variable. When you change the name property you change always the same property and your list displays always the same name

Comment: Yes, The problem is that I want to create a new person and add it to the list. However, that would also require me to make a new instance of test which I cant other then just adding a code of the new instance right? I actually want to add it manually when the app has started.

Comment: You don't have a constructor in your code. What do you mean by constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand your problem, there are a lot of things to change to make your form work properly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // BindingList is perfect here... istead of List. It automatically refreshes upon change.
    private BindingList<Test> m_Tests;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_Tests = new BindingList<Test>();

        listBox1.DataSource = m_Tests;
        // DisplayMember and ValueMember should be defined too here.
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new instance every time the button is clicked.
        // Since textBox1.Text is already a String... no need to convert it!
        // Thanks to BindingList, you don't need to refresh your binding...
        m_Tests.Add(new Test(textBox1.Text));
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private String m_Name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set { m_Name = value; }
    }

    public Test(String name)
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m_Name))
            return "NO NAME";

        return (m_Name + "   " + m_Name);
    }
}
```

Let's summarize my changes:

1. The list should not be part of your `Test` class, but of your `Form1`. This is where new instances should be properly added and managed, on a OOP point of view.
2. Since you are binding the list to a `ListBox` control, it's better to use `BindingList` (reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)). It was made exactly for this purpose and it can automatically handle changes.
3. The `BindingList` can be initialized when the `Form1` constructor is called and its linkage to the `ListBox` control must be defined as well within the same context. Don't forget to valorize `listBox1.DisplayMember` and `listBox1.ValueMember` properties too in order to set up a proper display of your underlying data.
4. When the button is clicked, all you have to do is to create a new instance of your `Test` class, with its name defined by `textBox1.Text`, and add it to the `BindingList`.
5. With your previous approach, since a single `Test` class instance was created within the `Form1` class, you were attempting to add the exact same instance every time your button was clicked... and that was producing basically nothing.
6. You can define a custom constructor for your `Test` class that accepts the name as argument, to facilitate the creation of new instances.
7. Properly handle your `Test.ToString()` override in order to avoid problems.
8. Overall, use the correct naming conventions to improve your code readability.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this for atleast a day. This worked perfectly with what I wanted to do. I'm going to look up more information on those Bindinglists, because I didnt know about them yet. Selfnote: I should probably be more clear about my problem in the future.

Comment: Don't worry, you have the time to learn. Meanwhile, I edited my answer to improve it a little bit.

Comment: It helped allot actually! About point 7. I had more detailed code. I will post that next time. People will probably understand, but it was in another language. The fast help here really encourages to go on.